# What nested panel combination should I use to achieve this

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

It just involves a JFrame and a JComboBox object.

I want to have a JComboBox aligned onto the center of a frame and it must not stretch to fill the entire width.

If I directly add it onto the frame, it will expand and stretch. I think I need to add it to a panel and add that panel to the frame. But how should I add it to that panel?

If I use flow layout for the panel and add the JComboBox, it will appear to the top of the frame and not center. :(

Comment: You have asked several questions, but not once have you "accepted" and answer. Hopefully this time you will remember to "accept" the answer that solves the problem. Its not hard all you do is click on the checkmark beside the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `GridBagLayout`:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(...);
frame.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
frame.add(comboBox, new GridBagConstraints());
```

Comment: Have you tried Absolute Layout? With this you can use the method .setBounds to set the position and the size of the combobox

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb, NO. Don't use AbsoluteLayout.

Comment: @MattMilna `Is there an alternative?` You asked a question, I gave you an answer. Why don't you like the answer. You already stated FlowLayout doesn't work, so why would you ask about it again. This solution answers your question. So why have you not yet "accepted" the answer?

Comment: @camickr: You seem like a senior member but begging for votes makes you look cheap and I don't want that to happen as you deserve some respect for your points. My answer has not been answered completely, so I'm not going to be forced to like when I'm still looking for an answer. My question to your answer is: **can't this be done using only grid, flow and border layouts?**

Comment: We all deserve respect when we take the time to help someone. You do not seem to understand this concept since you have asked several question and not once have you accepted an answer. Not only that you rarely even say "thank you". This question is an example. I gave you the standard  two line solution that is constantly given in this forum. You don't say thank but instead ask for an alternative. I asked you why you didn't like the solution but you have not replied. Instead it seems like you are looking for the most complex solution possible. Why would you want to do this???

Comment: All you need to tell me is if it's possible or not. Yes or No and you're on your way to getting a well deserved like. Until then, I can still like, but it would be meaningless.

Comment: camickr, I want to marry you. :)

Comment: BTW, I only know about those three layout managers, so that's why I asked.

Comment: All you need to do is "accept' past answers if you want the answer.  You get what you give. I already answered your `original question`. The common response would be to accept the answser, since it did answer the question and then maybe ask a follow up question. That way we know our effort is appreciated.

Comment: `I only know about those three layout managers` - So you would rather try to figure out some crazy solution using those layout manager, than use the simple solution provided or expand your knowledge by learning about a different layout manager? Read the tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: I liked and accepted your answer. Will you accept my marriage proposal because I've fallen in love with you?  It's not an instant thing. It's been happening over the last few weeks.

Comment: So, is it very difficult to achieve this using only those three layout managers?

Comment: See, this is the problem. Once we accept and give votes, that persons ceases to answer because he got what he wanted.

Comment: Now, I have unaccepted the answer again until you answer to my proposal and the following question.

Comment: `Once we accept and give votes, that persons ceases to answer` - seriously? You still have not yet accepted any of your other answers from your other postings and you have had over an hour to do so!!! Why do you think you are entitled to an answer within seconds??? Do you think you are the only person in the world? I was busy answering other questions on the forum. Fine, be childish. I will be back later this evening to see if you have learned to show appreciation for the effort we make by "accepting" answers in this and other postings.  If you make an honest effort, I make an honest effort.